# C++ analog to array of records in Pascal

Tags: c++, arrays

I'm learning C++. My main language is Free Pascal. In FP I can do this:

```
type
  TSomeType = (Foo1, Foo2, Foo3);

  TSomeRecord = record
    Field1: String;
    Field2: String;
  end;

var
  MyArray: array[TSomeType] of TSomeRecord;
```

So array has length=3. Then I can use it for example: `MyArray[Foo2].Field1 := 'Some string'` Can I do something similar in C++? Can't find solution in C++ array tutorials

Regards

Comment: I don't know FP, but that looks like an associative array to me.  If so, look at `std::map`.

Comment: in C you can use `struct` for a `record` and regular array. You can use it in C++ too but in C++ you should use objects instead (FP has ocjects too).

Comment: @ImreL: The only difference between a `struct` and a `class` in C++ is the default visibility of members and inheritance.

Comment: Can you explain exactly what that code for?

Comment: @EdS. actually the only difference is default visibility, a struct can inherit just like a class

Comment: @aaronman: You misread my comment.  I said *"the default visibility of members **and** inheritance."*.  Inheritance is *public* by default with `struct`s, private with `class`es.  There are two differences, the latter often forgotten and not as widely known.  I can see how the comment came off that way though.

Comment: You are correct interesting

Comment: I know C++ structures, but I didn't know how to do array where length is some enum. Problem solved by VoidStar. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Equivalent code in C++ would look something like this :

```
enum { Foo1, Foo2, Foo3, N };

struct SomeRecord
{
   string Field1;
   string Field2;
}

SomeRecord array[N];

array[Foo2].Field1 = "Some String";
```

Comment: This is the most direct equivalent, but in C++ it's more normal to use `vector<SomeRecord>` rather than a C-style array. A vector behaves mostly like an array, but can grow/shrink to hold more/fewer items. Combined with C++11 move semantics, it can be surprisingly efficient to "copy" around too - where possible, operations that look as if they require the array to be copied are implemented by messing with pointers behind the scenes. This makes life easier for passing/returning vector values to/from functions, among other things.